# problem with gridview.selectedvalue

Tags: asp.net, gridview, selectedvalue

i have wrote a simple website with asp and have girdview in it.i want when i click on select in gridview know the index of row(primary key) so i use from girdview.selectedvalue like this in

> page load

```
 if (str == "book")
        {
           //do some works
            if(this.IsPostBack)
            if (GridView37.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                Session["Download"] = GridView37.SelectedValue;
            }

        }
```

but my problem is that `GridView37.SelectedValue` is null forever.what is problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do is have a method that is called by the OnRowCommand event and within the method do:

```
public void MyMethod(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    ...
}
```

That gives the index of the row.